# Kivy application not starting

Tags: ubuntu, kivy

I just started up with Kivy. I have installed it using the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kivy
```

I tried the following example as per the doc:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="User Name"))
        self.username = TextInput(mutiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text="password"))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

When I execute the example from a terminal, nothing appeared on the screen. There were also no error messages.

The platform in which I am running is:

- Samsung Chromebook (ARM based)
- Ubuntu 13.10 installed using crouton

Comment: It may seem like no errors to you, however you should post your error log regardless. Also mention how you installed kivy? through ppa or manually ?

Comment: But i didn't get any error message. And i have written how i installed kivy

Comment: Then post the whole log, open ~/.kivy/config.ini and set log_level to debug then post the output.